# How to delete all records from the database that match my criteria

Tags: mysql, delete-row

When a user wants to delete his company it deletes just 1 record but all mathces should be deleted not just one.

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM `users_companies` WHERE `bedrijf_id`=".$_GET['del']." LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
```

This code just delete one record but has to delete all records,
can someone help me?

Comment: Sure! See that `?del=…` in your address bar? Change it to `?del=value;--`. That will cause it to comment out the `LIMIT 1`, since you’re *throwing your user input directly into your query*.

Comment: The id is a unique column?

Comment: No it isn't when the owner deletes his company it need to delete all companies from his Employees

Comment: See that part that says `LIMIT 1`?

Comment: @KevinKuijer Read something about SQL Injection. Your code is vulnerable to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using Limit 1, which makes the query targets only one row. if you want to delete all rows that match your where condition. try this :

```
 mysql_query("DELETE FROM users_companies WHERE bedrijf_id = '$_GET[del]'") or die(mysql_error());
```